# Filter objects manyTomany with users manyTomany

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to filter the model `Foo` by its manyTomany field `bar` with users `bar`.

Models

```
class User(models.Model):
  bar = models.ManyToManyField("Bar", verbose_name=_("Bar"), blank=True)

class Foo(models.Model):
  bar = models.ManyToManyField("Bar", verbose_name=_("Bar"), blank=True)

class Bar(models.Model):
  fubar = models.CharField()
```

with this

> user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

I want to gett all Foo's that have the same Bar's that the User has.
I would like this to work:

> bar = Foo.objects.filter(foo=user.foo)

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foos = Foo.objects.filter(bar__in=user.bar.all())
```